# How to create a Bitbucket PostRepositoryHooks after merging a PR in my JAVA project?

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I am trying to create a PostRepositoryHook in my Java project for automatically creating a PR to a different branch after merging a PR, but seems like the documentation is not updated, it refers to the 'Hooks' tab in the repository settings:

[image]

But all I can see is the 'WebHooks' tab which is not helping:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at documentation for Bitbucket Server, but you're using Bitbucket Cloud. They are not the same thing. (They are not even written in the same language.)

Comment: Thank's for the clarification. Do you know if I can achieve my goal using bitbucket cloud?

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud only offers webhooks or their CI/CD service (Pipelines). The webhook will send a JSON payload to a specified endpoint after a specified event, or Pipelines will execute a script in a container, but if you want a hook like what the BB Server documentation describes then it isn't possible.